# How to do a cubic spline interpolation on python with CuPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cupy

I am writing code by using GPU to keep doing cubic spline interpolation many times.
I know how to do it on numpy like using

```
scipy.interpolate.splrep
```

or

```
scipy.interpolate.interp1d(kind='cubic')
```

The interp1d is what I am using now for numpy arrays. But I need to run them on CuPy.

But how should I do it on CuPy? I have a x-values and y-values. And I also have an array with new x-values. The code I am writing now is going to calculate the new y-values for the new x-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this question myself now. I finished the interpolation algorithm. As ev-br's answer's suggestion, I just re-write the `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline` for cupy.

`scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline` contained a lot of functions which is not helpful if we just need an interpolation function.

The class `CubicSpline` has a parent class `scipy.interpolate.PPoly`, which also contained a lot of unnecessary functions if you only want an interpolation function. After a clear clean, I only used the classes `_PPolyBase`, `solve_banded()`, and `prepare_input()`.

The hardest part is the function `evaluate()` which is written in cython. Cython doesn't support cupy, so I used the numba which supports cuda to accelerate the loops' speed.

The head of the function `evaluate()` should be like:

```
@cuda.jit('void(complex128[:,:,:], float64[:], float64[:], complex128[:,:])')
def evaluate(c, x, xp, out):
```

There is an important thing that needs to notice which is the evaluation function is not a thread-safe function.

Only the first loop in `evaluate()` which is:

```
for ip in range(len(xp)):
    xval = xp[IP]
    ......
```

can use `cuda.grid(1)` and `cuda.gridsize(1)`

Also, I combine `evaluate_poly1()` and `find_interval_descending()` inside of `evaluate()` for better fit the numbe's cuda support.

The speed is super faster, which is about 3 to 4 times faster than the original scipy function.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/GavinJiacheng/Interpolation_CUPY

Comment: Great work! If I understand it correctly, doing the same with `splrep` seems more complicated as the corresponding function to your `evaluate` in `splrep` is a compiled `dfitpack.curfit`. (which raises the error "failed in converting argument of dfitpack.curfit to C/Fortran array).. .. hmm...

Comment: @niCkcAMel Sorry for the late reply. But I think you need to do more clean and cut for many functions which are not supposed to run math algorithms but some flag check. Many of them will need to call some check function in sippy which is fully useless.

Comment: no worries. Good job! I cloned your git code and gave it a try. Unfortunately it didn't result in any improvements (compared to unmodified scipy-CubicSpline) given my "usual" number of sample points (~30000). I reached a trade-off at around 4million sample points.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the source code scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline, which is pure python, and replace np.something with cupy.something one by one

Comment: But cupy is based on cuda. There is a cubic spline interpolation in cuda. I just want to find that functio in cupy. But I can't. I tried Google it but cannot find anything of it. I can do your suggestion but I am just wordning if there are some easy way to deal with it.

Comment: I tried this one. The sad thing is it also has many different functions inherent from scipy like solve_banded. I gave up. It is a big project if I just want to re-write the whole cubicSpline because I need to also re-write other functions in scipy.

Comment: Solve_banded specifically is easy, it's mostly a lapack call, which goes straight to cuda lapack

Comment: I think I didn't expalin it well..... solve_banded is just one example... there are other parts i need to change like solve(). But when I go to solve and solve_banded's file, they import more code. Then I go to the code they import, more imported functions. Then I need to modfiy a huge number of lines of code, which is so time consuming.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again. I am trying to re-write it. But here is a problem: CubicSpline is a subclass of PPoly, and for PPoly, it uses the function _ppoly.evaluate which is from the cython code _ppoly. Should I just simply change all numpy to cupy on the code _ppoly?